# How to write configmap for app dotnetcore

Tags: kubernetes

i have a docker-composes for app dotnetcore, I'm new to k8s, my app has quite a long envvariable. "ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection" as below

```
      productstudio:
    volumes:
      - ${USERPROFILE}/.aws:/root/.aws
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection=Username=someuser;Password=somepassword;Server=postgres;Port=5432;Database=somedb;Search Path=some
      - EventBus__Enable=true
      - EventBus__HostUri=rabbitmq://eventbus/
```

and i write configmap

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: be-productstudio-configmap
  labels:
    app: product-builder-be
    tier: backend
data:
  ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development
  EventBus__Enable: true
  EventBus__HostUri: rabbitmq://eventbus/
  ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection: |-
    Username=someuser;
    Password=somepassword;
    Server=postgres;
    Port=5432;
    Database=somedb;
    Search Path=some
```

But I got an error

```
Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "manifect-be.yml": ConfigMap in version "v1" cannot be handled as a ConfigMap: v1.ConfigMap.Data: ReadString: expects " or n, but found t, error found in #10 byte of ...|_Enable":true,"Event|..., bigger context ...|nSearch Path=productstudio\"","EventBus__Enable":true,"EventBus__HostUri":"rabbitmq://eventbus/"},"k|...
```

Can anyone help me, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two issues here:

1. The error you see means that the value `true` for `EventBus__Enable` is not quoted and it gets treated as a keyword that means a boolean true. Environment variables are strings and must be quoted in your yaml definition. You need to make it look more like this:

---

```
  EventBus__Enable: "true"
```

2. You should not use spaces in your key definitions of your `ConfigMap`:

---

```
Search Path=productstudio
```

as:

> Each key under the `data` or the `binaryData` field must consist of
> alphanumeric characters, `-`, `_` or `.`.

You can use the [official docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/) for a reference of a correctly configured ConfigMaps, for example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: game-demo
data:
  # property-like keys; each key maps to a simple value
  player_initial_lives: "3"
  ui_properties_file_name: "user-interface.properties"

  # file-like keys
  game.properties: |
    enemy.types=aliens,monsters
    player.maximum-lives=5
  user-interface.properties: |
    color.good=purple
    color.bad=yellow
    allow.textmode=true
```